# Haskell indentation doesn't line up function arguments

Tags: haskell, emacs, indentation

I'm using Emacs as my main Haskell editor, and as such, I of course use `haskell-mode` as the main mode for editing Haskell code.

Now for whatever reason, `haskell-indentation` doesn't offer an indent point for function arguments.

What I mean is that Emacs will consistently do this: (`□` is the other indent point(s))

```
myFunction = maybe arg1
□            arg2
□            arg3
```

Instead of doing this:

```
myFunction = maybe arg1
□            □     arg2
□            □     arg3
```

Sometimes I need to break functions up onto multiple lines due to the lines getting too long, but not having `haskell-mode` offer the right indent level is bugging me some.

Anything I can do to alleviate this?

## Edit

Seeing as I'm not the only one with this issue, I've opened a ticket on the `haskell-mode` github page [[here](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/813)]

Comment: Not at all a solution, but if you are moving `arg2` and `arg3` to separate lines you might as well fo the same with `arg1`.

Comment: @duplode yeah but then they'd still be lined up under `maybe` rather than being further indented... And seeing as haskell is an indentation based language, this could in theory cause some mis-interpretation

Comment: I see. FWIW, item 1.1 of [this HaskellWiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Emacs/Indentation) calls the haskell-mode behaviour you describe "debatably a bad choice" for this exact reason. Personally, I would probably indent this snippet as `myFunction = maybe<newline><4 spaces>longArg1<newline><4 spaces>longArg2<newline><4 spaces>longArg3`, and so it seems that, were I to use haskell-mode, I would run into a similar issue to yours.

Comment: The layout rules (which are all that care about indentation) only come into effect when one of `let/do/where/of` appears; and even within a layout context, as long as you don't *decrease* your indent so that `arg1` is indented by less than the `maybe` is, you run no risk of confusing the indentation.

Comment: I have the same issues. Usually I temporarily switch to simple indent mode using `turn-on-haskell-simple-indent` and then do the right level indent.

Comment: @amalloy Not true; `foo = do maybe arg1\n.........arg2` would be interpreted very differently from `foo = do maybe arg1\n...............arg2`, even though in neither case does the indentation decrease. (The former would be `foo = do { maybe arg1; arg2 }` while the latter would correctly be `foo = do { maybe arg1 arg2 }`.

Comment: I've submitted this issue as a ticket on the `haskell-mode` github, since it seems like I'm not the only one with this problem

Comment: @ElectricCoffee It will be nice if you can link the issue here. :)

Comment: @Sibi Edited the question with the link

Comment: AFAICT, `haskell-indent` (as opposed to `haskell-indentation`) gets this one right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the http://emacs.stackexchange.com/ site.

Answer (score 1):

The haskell-indentation  haskell-mode issue was closed last year and won't be fixed.

For desired behavior, use haskell-indent.